# Custom Validator fails to get Combobox ID

Tags: c#, ajax, combobox, customvalidator

I am using the custom Validator as Required Field validator fails for the Ajax Combobox, but I am not able to work it out for the Combobox, howeverr when I pass the Id of another Textbox in the custom Validator control to validate option, it works fine.

Below is my code:**Updated**

```
<ajax:ComboBox ID="Cmbx" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="AquaStyle textfont"
                                                AutoPostBack="true" DropDownStyle="DropDown" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
                                                CaseSensitive="false" ItemInsertLocation="Append"
                                                ValidationGroup="Validate" CausesValidation="true" />
```

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRequired" ControlToValidate="InstCmbx$TextBox" runat="server"
                                            ClientValidationFunction="validate" Display="None" ValidationGroup="Validate"/>
```

This is not working, I checked out the issue tracker on Ajax site as well, but they said that I must append "$TextBox" in the Id and it will work, but then also it is not working.

I am not able to call a simple javascript function from the same:

```
 function validate(sender, args) {
       alert("gasfkgsjkds");
   }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere on the control where you have specified the client side event validate();  You also have it set to autopostback, which means any js you want to execute will have to be executed from code behind with scriptmanager.

Comment: I have updated my code and it was written in the custom validator, which is calling the function validate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a way for doing this as this will not work directly for the Ajax combobox.
We need to extract the Text Box control from the Ajax Combobox and then calling a function on its "OnBlur" client side events.